# How can I fix in app billing init billing processor ? It is working sometimes but sometimes it is not working

Tags: flutter

Init billing processor before any operation begins

licenseKey your google play license key. Code editted.

```
  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    try {
      await FlutterInAppBilling.initBp(licenseKey);
    } on Exception catch (_) {}
  }
```

These are the logs I am getting when I try to init Billing processor. Please try the plugin [flutter_in_app_billing](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_in_app_billing)

```
W/BillingClient( 6922): Client is already in the process of connecting to billing service.
I/FlutterInAppBilling( 6922): Billing Processor Error
I/FlutterInAppBilling( 6922): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
D/Surface ( 6922): lockCanvas
D/GooglePlayConnection; ( 6922): IsConnected
I/FlutterInAppBilling( 6922): Billing Processor Initialized
D/AndroidRuntime( 6922): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime( 6922): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 6922): Process: net.thesocialapp.consumer, PID: 6922
E/AndroidRuntime( 6922): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
E/AndroidRuntime( 6922):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$Reply.reply(DartMessenger.java:139)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6922):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler$1.success(MethodChannel.java:238)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6922):    at com.vau.flutter_in_app_billing.FlutterInAppBillingPlugin.onBillingInitialized(FlutterInAppBillingPlugin.kt:154)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6922):    at com.anjlab.android.iab.v3.BillingProcessor$HistoryInitializationTask.onPostExecute(BillingProcessor.java:156)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6922):    at com.anjlab.android.iab.v3.BillingProcessor$HistoryInitializationTask.onPostExecute(BillingProcessor.java:127)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6922):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6922):    at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6922):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6922):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6922):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6922):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6977)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6922):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6922):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:528)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6922):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:910)
D/Surface ( 6922): Surface::disconnect(this=0x7c820c5000,api=2)
I/MPEG4Writer( 6922): Received total/0-length (249/0) buffers and encoded 249 frames. - Video
I/MPEG4Writer( 6922): reset()
D/MPEG4Writer( 6922): Video track stopping. Stop source
D/MPEG4Writer( 6922): Video track source stopping
D/MPEG4Writer( 6922): Video track source stopped
D/MPEG4Writer( 6922): Video track stopped. Stop source
D/MPEG4Writer( 6922): Stopping writer thread
D/MPEG4Writer( 6922): 0 chunks are written in the last batch
D/MPEG4Writer( 6922): Writer thread stopped
I/MPEG4Writer( 6922): writeMoovBox()
I/MPEG4Writer( 6922): Ajust the moov start time from 102875584182 us -> 102875584182 us
I/MPEG4Writer( 6922): writeMoovBox() end
I/MPEG4Writer( 6922): The mp4 file will not be streamable.
I/MPEG4Writer( 6922): release()
I/MPEG4Writer( 6922): reset()
D/MPEG4Writer( 6922): Video track stopping. Stop source
I/zygote64( 6922): Do partial code cache collection, code=500KB, data=318KB
I/zygote64( 6922): After code cache collection, code=495KB, data=313KB
I/zygote64( 6922): Increasing code cache capacity to 2MB
D/TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore( 6922): Storing event with priority=HIGHEST, name=FIREBASE_CRASHLYTICS_REPORT for destination cct
D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler( 6922): Scheduling upload for context TransportContext(cct, HIGHEST, MSRodHRwczovL2NyYXNobHl0aWNzcmVwb3J0cy1wYS5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MS9maXJlbG9nL2xlZ2FjeS9iYXRjaGxvZ1xBSXphU3lCcnBTWVQ0RkZMMDlyZUhKaTZIOUZZZGVpU25VVE92Mk0=) with jobId=552285206 in 1000ms(Backend next call timestamp 1653049603958). Attempt 1
I/Process ( 6922): Sending signal. PID: 6922 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Can you provide more context of where you are calling this? It looks like it may be getting called multiple times.

Comment: The plugin also looks very error-prone with how it handles async results. There is a race condition where the same `methodResult` could be called  after two separate internal responses.

Comment: Yes @DanHarms, That is exactly what is happening. How can I prevent this?

Comment: It would help if you shared your code. Essentially, you have to make sure you never call the method channel until the previous one has returned.

Comment: Okay, I am running this code ` FlutterInAppBilling.initBp(yourlicenseKey);` inside initState() Method.

Comment: @DanHarms I have done an edit on the code

Comment: You will also need to include where you are making other calls to that lib. The init may still be in progress when you make another call for example.

Comment: You see, The screen crushes immediately after the screen open. However, it works once in a while(I don't know how). I am making another call on the same page. But with a click of a button.

Comment: Since init only needs to happen once, move it into your `main` prior to the call to `runApp`.

Comment: I moved the method prior to runApp and the app is still crushing.

Comment: Any package you can recommend for In-app-billing

Comment: @DanHarms please see my message

Comment: I don't have any recommendations unfortunately. Verify you are not calling that lib anywhere else. It doesn't look like it would fail with only one call.

Comment: Maybe this `implementation 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:2.0.3'`

Comment: @DanHarms What If I write a function that will be executed only once

Comment: That is what `main` is.

Comment: I can use another logic, like shared_preference. Since the lib is working well when I run on the first time, Second time it crushes